# How do I use a dynamic form action using angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have an http get method that generates a dynamic form upload URL.  When I display it on the screen it works.  When I put it in the action tag of a form it does not appear.

```
    <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="data-controller">
    <form action="{{uploadUrl}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

data-controller.js

```
    var url = "[MY URL]";
$http.get(url).success(function(response) {
    $scope.uploadUrl = response;
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try `ng-attr-action="{{uploadUrl}}"` should work

Comment: @pankajparkar: why will `action="{{uploadUrl}}"` not work considering `uploadUrl` to be a string?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli ngDeveloper has already given answer..which is correct i think..I missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response` is an object, not a string. You would have to do either `response.data`, or altogether `response.data.url`, based on how the response is returned. You can try `console.log(response)`, and then look at the output in your Browser Console using F12 > Console, to see what the variable is outputting.

Example:
`$scope.uploadUrl = response.data.url;`